# Python: How can I parse { apple: "1" , orange: "2" } into Dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have received an output , it likes this.

```
{
    orange: '2',
    apple: '1',
    lemon: '3'
}
```

I know it is not a standard JSON format, but is it still possible to parse into Python Dictionary type? Is it a must that **orange , apple , lemon** must be quoted?

Thanks you

Comment: Wherever you get this output from, you should tell the person to fix it and produce valid JSON (imo).

Comment: Yes, the name of an name/value pair of JSON object needs to be a properly quoted JSON string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is valid [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) (a superset of JSON). Use [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) to parse it:

```
>>> s = '''
... {
...     orange: '2',
...     apple: '1',
...     lemon: '3'
... }'''
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load(s)
{'orange': '2', 'lemon': '3', 'apple': '1'}
```

More, since there is a tab space inside the string s, we better remove it before parsing into yaml.

```
s=s.replace('\t','')
```

Otherwise, the above string cannot be parsed.

Comment: that's fanastic. That's what I want to do!